# Django 1.7: How to define utf8 numbers in django?

Tags: python, django, utf-8, django-models, django-admin

I have an `IntegerField` in my Django model as follows:

```
class Item(models.Model):    
    related_room = models.ForeignKey(Room)
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    item_price = models.IntegerField()
```

the `item_price` is an integer value. When I use Django admin to create a new `Item` it gives me validation error for the `item price` because it has the value `۱۵۰۰`

[image: Validation Image]

But when I change the value to `1500`(not its unicode version) it works properly. All of my tables character-set and my DB character-set are `UTF-8`. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks.

Comment: Please post a stacktrace.  You can produce one by implementing your own form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug in the file `django/forms/fields.py` line 261. The line should be

```
        value = int(smart_text(value))
```

Comment: Thanks it solves the problem :) but in the admin panel it is the not-unicode version e.g. 1500.